# Is this possible with CSS

Tags: css

I want a CSS layout , two column left one is 40% and right the rest (60%) ... but I also want the left one not to gwt smaller than say 200 pixels when the browser is resized. 
I use absolute positioning. My css is like this

```
#LeftSection
{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
#RightSection
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 40%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that position:fixed is what you want for the LeftSection?

Answer (score 3):

Use [min-width](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/minwidth.html) and the various hacks to get it to work with IE (see link).

**EDIT**: I shouldn't say hacks. Use conditional comments to include an IE-only stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks! I did not even know that property existed :)
Would you pls give the link again? for IE nightmare

Comment: The link is the word "min-width" in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this one?

```
min-width:200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out PPK's [QuirksMode compatibility tables for CSS](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) properties including [min-width/height](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/width.html).  This will help you when you run into the inevitable situations where certain browsers (IE6) don't act the same way as the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions with min-width for LeftSection will lead to overlapping of the two `<div />` or whatever block element you use, e.g. if the browser window is 400px wide, then LeftSection will be 200px wide, but RightSection will be 240px wide and have a margin-left of 160px, therefore overlap by 40px. Unfortunately, there is no min-margin style in CSS, so IIRC it will not be possible to totally avoid overlapping for small browser windows with your markup.